# Leave something (behind) somewhere

Tags: idioms, expressions, idioms-in-context

> **[Leave something behind**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/leave-sth-sb-behind):
> to leave a place without taking something with you:

- We left in a hurry and I must have **left my keys behind**.

Now I need to include "home" within the idiom!
I was wondering whether the sentence below is idiomatic. If no, the. how would you imply the same message in natural English?

> - I've left my wallet **behind** at home.

I'm asking this question because I was faced with many cases in which "behind" had been removed from the construction above. Since that was contrary to the original idiom, I always thought there should be a missing pint here that I do not know about it. That was why I decided to post a new thread here.

Please let me know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **left (somewhere)** or **left behind**. For the second one, **somewhere** is optional. So:

> I left my wallet **behind (at home)**.

or

> I left my wallet **at home**.

(it's not perfect tense as it's a past action.)

and

> We left in a hurry and I must have left my keys **behind (at home)**.

or

> We left in a hurry and I must have left my keys **at home**.

So you can get away with or without "behind", but it depends on the sentence structure as to whether it's correct usage or not.

**EDIT:** ( ) are optional items.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you intend the "**(at home)**" parts as optional parts of the example sentences, or descriptions of what "behind" refers to.

Comment: @gotube I edited my question. "behind" refers to some unspecified previous location.

Comment: Based on your edits, your answers including "at home" are wrong. "I left my wallet behind at home" is bad grammar.